# Spring Boot JPA Like query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying toimplement a search function for my table of users. I want to make a JpaRepository method that will give me a pageable list of my users that have their emails containing a given String, how can I do that?
This is whatIhave tried
The repository:

```
    @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> { 
    Page<User> findByEmailContaining(String email, Pageable pageable);  
}
```

The servive:

```
public Page<User> findPaginatedEmail(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection, String text) {
    Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
        Sort.by(sortField).descending();
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
    return this.userRepository.findByEmailContaining(text, pageable);
}
```

Sometimes it works and populates my table and sometimes it doesn't. What is the problem? How do I implement it?

It works fine but after a time it simply breaks I dont know why, then it wont find anything

Comment: well now, i found the problem...The method is working, but I was on a different page (say page 7) instead of page 1/2, and everytime I would search it would return me one page or two pages...but being on page 7, what I was seeing was no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many approaches, in case here it is been used the SimpleJpaRepository calling the findAll Method with parameters Specification and Pageable, returning the Page interface.

```
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
import org.springframework.data.web.SortDefault;

    @GetMapping(path = "/pageable")
    public Page<?> getCountries(@RequestParam(name = "countryName", required = false) String countryName,
            @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 20) @SortDefault.SortDefaults({
                    @SortDefault(sort = "id", direction = Sort.Direction.ASC) }) Pageable pageable)
    {
        
    }
```

My Repository interface :

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
 

public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Country> { 
}
```

In case of having dynamic queries i use :

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<T>
```

the spring data jpa :

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor<T>

Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);


org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>

    public Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable) {

        TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(spec, pageable);
        return isUnpaged(pageable) ? new PageImpl<T>(query.getResultList())
                : readPage(query, getDomainClass(), pageable, spec);
    }
```

> the repository CountryRepository calling the method findAll(@Nullable
> Specification spec, Pageable pageable) returns the Page

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Product, Integer> {

    List<Product> findAllByPrice(double price, Pageable pageable);
}
```

You just add one extra function parameter Pageable and also you need extend your Repository class with PagingAndSortingRepository instead of JpaRepository

[Pagination example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)